# Quantum energy levels vs. mass

Tags: mass-energy, quarks

TL;DR given a system comprised of two bound particles with masses $m_1, m_2$, and given energies of bound states $E_n$ between the two particles according to the non-relativistic Schrodinger equation, why should the measured masses of such system be equal to $M_n = m_1 + m_2 + E_n$?

Long(er) version: recently I stumbled across the discussion around non-relativistic potential models of charmonium and bottomonium and it is pretty popular to describe their interaction with a static potential $V (r) = - (4\alpha/3) r^{-1} + \sigma r$, assuming that these heavy mesons are non-relativistic enough. People then solve for energy levels of such potential from Schrodinger equation and fit for measured masses of charmonia and bottomonia. However, it turns out that one should fit for
$$
M = 2 m + E
$$
where $M$ are the measured masses, $m$ is the mass of a charm quark and $E$ are the calculated energy levels (with parameters $\alpha, \sigma$ and $m$ to be fitted for).

My question is: why $M = 2 m + E$? Sure, it makes sense somehow that the observed mass of a composite object is it's sum of its compoments masses + interaction energy between the components, but is there any formal "proof" of this? Is this true only in non-relativistic case, or is it true in relativistic systems as well?

Some thoughts:

- classically, mass is the proportionality coefficient; take an object, apply a force F on it, then it's acceleration will be a = (1/mass) F. This is by definition a classical thing and not how it is detected on any deeper level
- if an object is unstable (and $c \bar c$ and $b \bar b$ systems are), one can measure the 4-vectors of the products of the decay, sum them and square them (simplified version). The resulting number is drawn from a distribution that is centered around the mass of the object and has a finite width related to its lifetime. But this is an intrinsically relativistic point, so I don't know how energy levels obtained from non-relativistic Schrodinger equation and their relation to the measured masses enter the picture here
- for typical hadrons, the mass of the hadron has little to do with masses of it's quarks, the most mass comes from the strong interactions. However, in this $M = 2 m + E$ the energy levels $E$ are comparable to the mass (everything is fitted of course). ($m_c \approx 1.25 \,\text{GeV}$, while $M_{c \bar c}$ of the lowest state is around $3 \,\text{GeV}$)

Comment: You are wrong about hydrogen.

Comment: Care to elaborate which part? H atom is 1.007825u, while proton is 1.007276466621(53)u. Electron has mass 0.000548579909070(16) u. Subtract and you do not get zero or 13.6 eV.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_hydrogen#Hydrogen-1_(protium)) for more precise mass of hydrogen. 1.007 825 032 241 u - 1.007 276 466 621 u - 0.000 548 579 909 u = -0.000 000 014 289 u = -13.4 eV. The missing 0.2 eV is just from experimental uncertainty. There is no discrepancy of 160 keV!

Comment: Actually, 1.007825032241 - 1.007276466621 - 0.000548579909 = -0.000000014289 so it's -13.31 eV. I can't explain the difference. I think we're diverging from my original question.

Comment: I fixed the subtraction. And, yes, it should be -13.3, not -13.4. (Too late to edit.) And certainly not 160 keV!

Comment: You claimed that hydrogen did not obey the expected formula. It *does*.

Comment: Okay, I removed it.

Comment: The standard reason for this is that $E = Mc^2$ for all objects at rest. (One could even take this to be the _definition_ of rest mass.) So to figure out what $M$ is, you need to add up all the contributions to $E$. Is there a reason you don't like this answer?

Comment: This is circular reasoning. I asked why M = 2m + E. You say because E (not the same E as I just wrote) = M c^2 and I have to add all contributions to E. That brings it back to the question in the beginning.

Comment: Energy is additive, because this assumption is consistent with experiments, as we just discussed for hydrogen.

Answer (score 0):

In the non-relativistic case we still have that $E=mc^2$. Since energy is a conserved quantity, any mass differences resulting from a process must be compensated for by energy differences (units are often used with $c=1$).

Comment: I guess my conceptual problem with this, is that the rest mass is something absolute. However potential is not (we cannot measure EM potentials, only E and B fields), so I can add any constant to it and the corresponding force will stay the same. However, this implies that the mass can shift up and down freely as I add any arbitrary constant to the potential (that will reflect in the energy levels).

Comment: For the hydrogen atom and discrepancy of 0.2 eV: I actually don't have much insight how exactly is the ground state energy measured (maybe apart from measuring how much energy is released when free electron and proton form an atom). I know that we can very precisely measure differences in energies (further supporting the claim that absolute numbers do not mean much), not that sure about the exact 13.6 eV. Anyway, how can we then confidently say that the missing 0.2 eV is due to imprecise measurements? Why can't it be a result of an arbitrary constant in potential?

Comment: I am afraid you are looking for an entire course in physics, not answers that can be given in a forum.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what course exactly? I'm in the middle of my PhD and would like to focus on my research, but if there's a class that would still benefit me, I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: I think you are confusing field potential with the energy of the field. Adding a constant (or gauge function)  to the e.m potential does not alter the energy-density of an e.m. field which can be given $u = (\mathbf E^2 + \mathbf B^2)/2$. The relationship between mass, energy and momentum remains absolute in special relativity, and applies also to the photons which can be seen as comprising the field.

Comment: Wait, let's take Schrodinger equation. Let's say the potential is $- \frac{4 \alpha}{3 r} + V_0$. Then the energies of this system are $- \varepsilon_1/n^2 + V_0$, aren't they? By just displacing the potential by $V_0$ I displaced the energy levels, thus if $M_n = m_1 + m_2 + E_n$, then I managed to pack more or less mass into the system (or even negative mass if I choose $V_0$ to be $ - 10^{20} \, \text{eV}$.

Comment: I think you have introduced an unobservable phase change into the wave function. As with classical mechanics, the arbitrary constant in energy levels is removed by the relativistic relationship. This completely determines the relationship between mass and energy, so that it applies in the non-relativistic case as well. A good  treatment of sr from first principles should clear it up.